# Draw bold axes in Matlab properly

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axes, visual-glitch

Default axes are very thin in Matlab plots and I tried to make them bold with

```
set(gca, 'fontsize', 18, 'linewidth', 2)
```

But the lines do not match properly together in the four **edges**. The following MWE demonstrates the problem:

```
plot(1,1,'linewidth', 5)
set(gca, 'fontsize', 18, 'linewidth', 5)
box on
print -dpng example
```

[image: example with glitch in the edges]

**How can I draw bold axes properly in Matlab?**

Answer (score 3):

How about drawing the four thick lines manually with `plot`?

```
plot(1,1,'linewidth', 5)
hold on
xl = xlim;
yl = ylim;
plot([xl(1) xl(2) xl(2) xl(1) xl(1)],...
     [yl(1) yl(1) yl(2) yl(2) yl(1)],....
     'k', 'linewidth', 5)
set(gca, 'fontsize', 18)
print -dpng example
```

Or, as noted by @thewaywewalk, that long `plot` line can be replaced by the simpler

```
rectangle('linewidth',5)
```

Result in Matlab R2010b:

[image]

Result in Matlab R2014a:
[image]

Result in Matlab R2014b:

[image]

Comment: For any reason your solution is not working for me (Matlab 2014a with HG2-Update), it looks the same like in the OPs case. Apart from that: just simply `rectangle('linewidth',5)` would do the job as well, as default the rectangle is drawn regarding the axes limits. But anyhow, with the same issue the OP describes.

Comment: to be on the save side you could add `'marker','s','MarkerFaceColor','k','MarkerEdgeColor','none'` to your `plot` command, not working with the rectangle command though, at least not in this version.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for the comments. I've edited my answer to include the `rectangle` line. It's weird you get the wrong behaviour, because the OP edited my answer with his results in R2014a and it seems to work. Maybe it's the hg2 update